# I am trying to print a dictionary containing strings with newline but "\n" is getting printed instead of newline

Tags: python, string, dictionary, formatting

[Output][1]```
now = datetime.now()
env = 'IPC1 \nE1/E2'

report = {'Date': now, 'Environment': env, 'Array Name' : 'Hyperstore1'}

report_df = pd.DataFrame(report)

html = """\

```
<head></head>

<body>

    {0}

</body>
```

""".format(build_table(report_df, 'blue-dark'))

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW61A.jpg
```

Comment: You aren't printing a string, you are printing a dictionary containing strings. The default string representation of a dictionary is like that. If you want to format it differently, you have to write code for it.

Comment: No this is not helping me....can you please let me know what I am supposed to code so that it can be printed in two lines

Comment: I have to mail this report futher after converting it to a dataframe and then into a HTML table... please help get into newline .

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question and show the exact output you expect to get in this example?

Comment: Yes I have edited it and this is the exact output I want ...please have a look

Comment: That made the question less clear. What is `build_table`?

Comment: Also, you still didn't show the output you want to get. You only showed the code you tried to use. What is the problem with this code?

Comment: build_table is a function of pretty_html_table

Comment: We use it like - from pretty_html_table import build_table

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
env = 'IPC1 \nE1/E2'
report = {'Date': now, 'Environment': env}
print(*(f"{k}: {v}" for k, v in report.items()), sep='\n')
```

**Output**

```
Date: 2021-06-17 13:57:41.228941
Environment: IPC1 
E1/E2
```

Comment: But I have to send this report through mail in form of HTML table after converting it into dataframe . This is not working in that case